# measure very small ( negative and positve ) Voltage with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

How can I measure Voltage in Range -100mv to +100mv with Arduino ,
Is that an Arduino-shield can do that ?

Comment: You need to turn it 100% positive. Make it 2.4V to 2.6V by adding 2.5V to it. Then just use the ADC.  If you like, increase the range by amplifying the signal at the same time.

Comment: @Majenko that is output from circuit , so i can't add any voltage to this output

Comment: Yes you can. You take your existing voltage and add another voltage to it. It's commonly done with op-amps. Here's examples: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/opampvar5.html

Comment: @Majenko can I use UA471cp ? , can you draw and post the Schematic please ?

Comment: Yes, you can probably use that chip, and there are plenty of summing amplifier examples online to pick from.