# can I use Arduino cuurent-shield-sensor to measure very small voltage?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide

I want to measure very small voltage in small Range -100/+100 mv from a circuit,
can Arduino-shield ACS712 (max471) do that direkt ?

Comment: That chip is for measuring current, not voltage.

Comment: @user59015, why didn't you edit the [original question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/68136/measure-very-small-negative-and-positve-voltage-with-arduino) instead of posting this new second question?

Comment: you want something like an ina219

Comment: You could use an opamp circuits to amplify and limit the signal to whatever range you like...